# How secure Google Compute Engine is?

Tags: security, cloud, ids

We're moving to GCE and we want to know how secure it is.

Do we need to install our own intrussion detection/prevention software on our VM Instances? (Tripware, Ossec, Snort).
or does GCE handle security by itself? how much must we do in this regard?

We want to protect our CE (compute engine) from:

- Unauthorized access to our files.
- Interception of Data.

Thanks.

Comment: To help make your question clearer, and to help folks in the solutions/ideas they provide, you might add some clarification about what you mean by "secure".  Specifically, what security concerns do you have?

Comment: Ok, I had edited the principal post: "We want to protect our CE (compute engine) from: Unauthorized access to our files, Interception of Data" Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[It's secure](https://cloud.google.com/security/). Make sure you use TLS for data in transit, and if your data is sensitive you could encrypt it when it's at rest.